# App Linking working but not showing any changes in dumpsys

Tags: android

I have done everything to setup App Linking. My app starts right up when I fire off intent:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.example.com"
```

But when I check system via adb:

```
adb shell dumpsys package domain-preferred-apps
```

I still get undefined status:

```
Package: com.example.applinkingtest
Domains: www.example.com
Status:  undefined
```

Any guess why this is the case? I'm waiting the 20 seconds recommended by the docs.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm having the same issue...